# OOM error in a child step (group by key) of CombineFn Perkey with HotKeyFanout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, spring-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I have a beam batch job runs on Dataflow. Summary flow of this job:

- -> Read from Big Query // Hundreds of million records
- -> Transform each big query record to Order event
- -> Key each Order event by using its customer id
- -> Apply combine function (with hotKeyFanout = 50) to calculate average price of all orders per customer
- -> Transform combined result into a single TableRow
- -> Write TableRow to BigQuery

I know that some customers can have millions of orders (hot key problem)
So I apply advanced combineFn with hotKeyFanout (50)

[image: Combine Function]

I was pretty sure that with this setup, memory won’t be a problem, because data is aggregated with Accumulator , hence reducing memory footprint in the pipeline.

Yet I ran into a problem with a small step of CombineFn, called GroupByKey, which I don’t really understand the purpose of this step. (Perhaps it is the merge accumulator step?)

[image: Dataflow combine step expanded]

Looking at the heap analysis from cloud profiler, there seems to be a huge string builder object ~1GB :
[image: Heap analysis on worker with OOM problem]

At the moment I’m pretty lost on why there is a huge amount of data ended up in a worker when i already have hotKeyFanout option. My guess at the moment is that 50 splits for hot key isn’t enough, so there is a huge split bundle. I tend to increase hotkeyfanout to larger number, but I’m not sure if it will solve the problem or I’m looking at the problem from the wrong angle.

Looking for suggestions/recommendation on what I did wrong here.

Comment: Can you share the profiler interface with the stacks toggled and with more information? Have you tried using a machine type with higher memory: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#n1-high-memory?

Comment: Your CombineFn looks fine and as you point out shouldn't use more memory no matter how many elements it processes. Are you sure it's this part of the stage that's failing? Can you try running the pipeline up to the CombinePerKey (excluding the creation of TableRow and writing it to BigQuery) to see if that's really the issue. (Note that when a worker OOMs, all the stages currently running are implicated because we don't have a way of telling which stage is actually using too much memory, just that the worker as a whole was.)

Comment: FYI, you could use https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.26.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Mean.java#L95

Comment: Any update on what worked on for you?

Comment: @Ram , sorry for late reply , it turned out there was 1 collection in the accumulator was getting too big, hence causing the OOM problem.